# Field validations don't get called if react-admin SimpleForm has a validate function

Tags: react-admin

Consider the following code:

```
const validateLetterTypeForm = (values: Partial<ILetterType>) => {
    const errors: Partial<ILetterType> = {};
    //TODO: put code to validate form here
    //https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html#validation-mode
    

    return errors;
};

const LetterTypeForm2 = () => {
    return (
        <SimpleForm noValidate validate={validateLetterTypeForm}>
            <TextInput source="businessArea" required validate={requiredField}/>
            <TextInput source="letterTypeDesc" required validate={requiredField}/>
        </SimpleForm>
    );
};
```

We noticed that, if SimpleForm has a validate function defined (as above), the validate functions in the fields do not get called. Is this an expected react-admin SimpleForm behavior? Is there a way to have both form and field level validations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `react-admin 4.X.X` you cannot have both validations.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html

They are multiple workaround to do both but none works correctly in all situations.

If you only have this `<SimpleForm/>` I suggest that you verify on the SimpleForm validate that the values are set and remove the fields `required validate={requiredField}`